# Is it possible to find the physical location of someone connected to a wifi

Tags: wifi

I suppose the question is in the title, is it possible to find the physical location of someone connected to a wifi network.

Say two people are connected on the same network, can one of them know where the other is exactly, im not looking for how to do it answer, just if it possible and some general information on the matter.

Comment: With current hardware, probably not. Eventually, sure. https://www.technologyreview.com/s/542561/wi-fi-trick-gives-devices-super-accurate-indoor-location-fixes/

Comment: Depends whether you're only allowed to use the hardware already in your computer or if you can build your own.  The question isn't clear on that point.

Answer (score 1):

Other people using the same WiFi: no.

An administrator of a large WiFi system: plausible. Signal strengh to different access points can be used to imprecisely estimate ones location.